# How to get information and output Sum of Absolute Difference in HM Test Model?

Tags: hevc, h.265

I am using software reference HM Test Model 16.9, How to get information and output of Sum of Absolute Difference in HM Test Model? Is it possible to configure it via config file and save it into text file? I already read the software manual but can't find any.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SAD, I am not sure.
But I know that at the encoder side, you can print out MSE both at the frame level and sequence level simply by setting the CFG parameters `PrintFrameMSE` and `PrintSequenceMSE`.

Comment: Thanks sir @mohsen-abdoli it works, So for SAD, is it calculated manually?

Comment: @kaito87 For the SAD calculation, to my knowledge, there is no other way than code modification. It might be a bit complicated as you will probably have to duplicate a lot of functions and variables related to MSE calculation. Once duplicated, you need to replace the MSE formula with SAD in all occurrences.

Comment: Thanks for advice sir @mohsen-abdoli